# Average distance between a random point and the closest of a set of random points

Tags: co.combinatorics

Create a set of n randomly placed points in a unit square. Then create another random point in the unit square. What is the average distance between this point and the closest of the n points?

Comment: Euclidean distance?

Comment: this is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2565546/87355